# xarray DataArray.sel returns coords not assigned originally to the data

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a multivariate dataset stored in xarray DataArrays. I'd like to select a part of the DataArray and drop the coords that are not contained in the set of coords I am selecting. For example:

```
ar1 = xr.DataArray(np.random.random((5,3,3)),
                  coords={'range':np.arange(0,5), 'vars':['var1','var2','var3'], 'axes':['ax1','ax2','ax3']},
                  dims=['range', 'vars', 'axes'],
                  name='ar1' )
ar2 = xr.DataArray(np.random.random((5,1,2)),
                  coords={'range':np.arange(0,5), 'vars':['var4'],'labels':['l1','l2']},
                  dims=['range', 'vars', 'labels'],
                  name='ar2' )

dar = ar1.combine_first(ar2)
dar = dar.sel({'vars':['var1','var2','var3'], 'axes':['ax1','ax2','ax3']}, drop=True)
dar
```

`DataArray.sel` yields the following:

```
    <xarray.DataArray 'ar1' (range: 5, vars: 3, axes: 3, labels: 2)>
    array([[[[0.38942957, 0.38942957],
             [0.45528695, 0.45528695],
             [0.49853459, 0.49853459]],
             ...
            [[0.67717998, 0.67717998],
             [0.89777309, 0.89777309],
             [0.47580058, 0.47580058]]]])
    Coordinates:
      * vars     (vars) object 'var1' 'var2' 'var3'
      * range    (range) int64 0 1 2 3 4
      * axes     (axes) <U3 'ax1' 'ax2' 'ax3'
      * labels   (labels) <U2 'l1' 'l2'
```

But `var1, var2, var3` do not have coord `labels`. How do I get rid of the extra coord preserving the data structure of the selected part?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Desired output

```
   <xarray.DataArray 'ar1' (range: 5, vars: 3, axes: 3)>
    array([[[[0.38942957, 0.38942957],
             [0.45528695, 0.45528695],
             [0.49853459, 0.49853459]],
             ...
            [[0.67717998, 0.67717998],
             [0.89777309, 0.89777309],
             [0.47580058, 0.47580058]]]])
    Coordinates:
      * vars     (vars) object 'var1' 'var2' 'var3'
      * range    (range) int64 0 1 2 3 4
      * axes     (axes) <U3 'ax1' 'ax2' 'ax3'
```

Comment: Why use `combine_first` if you don't want to combine the coords? Does `xr.merge` do what you want?

Comment: This is an example to generate a similar dataset with the one that I am dealing with. Ultimately, I'd like to perform an operation only in the selected portion of the data without recreating the DataArray from each component

Comment: Looking at `dar` before the `sel` shows that it _does_ have data on the labels dimension. Is your question how you combine `ar1` & `ar2` differently, or how to select some subset of data from `dar`?

Comment: The second; how to select data from ``dar`` without ``labels``

Comment: `labels` is a dimension on `dar`! i.e. it's 5x3x3x2 with the 2 being the labels dimension. What do you mean select without labels? Maybe show your intended result?

Comment: This is what I am not fully grasping. How can it be a dimension of  ``dar`` since the original data of ``ar1`` were not assigned this dimension? Question updated with the desired output.

Comment: What are you expecting would happen to the `label` dimension of `ar2`? Which values in `ar2` are you expecting would go into `dar`?